# TypeError upon authenticating user using Google OAuth 2

Tags: google-oauth

I'm using the OAuth 2 flow for installed applications. The application redirects the user to authenticate. After authenticating the user goes to authorize my application to access their account. The browser never loads the next page and I see a Javascript type error in the debug console.

**Steps to reproduce the issue:**

1. Direct the user to https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth with the redirect_uri set to out of bounds (urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob)
2. Authentication works fine
3. Upon clicking the Accept button on the authorization page the script throws a TypeError

**Expected output:**
The browser should load the page with the auth code in the title.

**Actual results:**
Both the *Accept* and the *Cancel* buttons are disabled and clicking them has no effect. The script should check whether the `sessionStorage` property is available in the browser's `window` object.

Here is the output from the debug console:

```
TypeError: Result of expression 'window.sessionStorage' [undefined] is not an object.
 at https://apis.google.com/_/scs/abc-static/_/js/k=gapi.gapi.en.a0irxetnvx4.O/m=googleapis_client,plusone/exm=appcirclepicker/rt=j/sv=1/d=1/ed=1/am=EA/rs=AItRSTMM3Tduq30stOAPMPXAx0A6ctSSsg/cb=gapi.loaded_1 : 13
 at https://apis.google.com/_/scs/abc-static/_/js/k=gapi.gapi.en.a0irxetnvx4.O/m=googleapis_client,plusone/exm=appcirclepicker/rt=j/sv=1/d=1/ed=1/am=EA/rs=AItRSTMM3Tduq30stOAPMPXAx0A6ctSSsg/cb=gapi.loaded_1 : 18
 at https://ssl.gstatic.com/gb/js/smm_f3709b68f5d2f2cb75de9df3f7819c89.js : 151
 at https://ssl.gstatic.com/gb/js/smm_f3709b68f5d2f2cb75de9df3f7819c89.js : 154
 at https://ssl.gstatic.com/gb/js/smm_f3709b68f5d2f2cb75de9df3f7819c89.js : 151
 at https://ssl.gstatic.com/gb/js/smm_f3709b68f5d2f2cb75de9df3f7819c89.js : 153
 at https://ssl.gstatic.com/gb/js/smm_f3709b68f5d2f2cb75de9df3f7819c89.js : 153
 at https://ssl.gstatic.com/gb/js/smm_f3709b68f5d2f2cb75de9df3f7819c89.js : 153
 at https://ssl.gstatic.com/gb/js/smm_f3709b68f5d2f2cb75de9df3f7819c89.js : 153
```

Comment: Related discussion: https://groups.google.com/d/topic/google-picasa-data-api/0P0RLAuKGrk/discussion

Comment: Jakub, did you ever find an answer to this? I'm getting this same error when I use AS3/Adobe AIR's HTMLLoader to do the OAuth. The errors appear as at the page where the user accepts the permissions. The user circles don't render and upon clicking the Accept button, it just grays out and goes nowhere.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

(1) delete next from url:

```
<a href="{% url 'social:begin' 'google-oauth2' %}?next={{ request.path }}">Login with Google</a>
```

to be like this:

```
<a href="{% url 'social:begin' 'google-oauth2' %}">Login with Google</a>
```

(2) set the LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL to the proper value (in the settings file):

like:

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'login_success'     
#'login_success' is a url name, change it to your valid url name
```