# Google OAuth accept button enabled but doesn't respond using Adobe AIR's built in browser. TypeError with window.sessionStorage occurs on load

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air, google-api, google-oauth

I am using Adobe AIR 3.8 and manually generating all of the OAuth calls for my application. Tracing out the user agent of the HTMLLoader that I am using for the OAuth calls in AS3, I get the follow:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X; en) AppleWebKit/533.19.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) AdobeAIR/3.8
```

I am able to get passed the user login portion and up to the part where they need to accept the permissions to move on. However, AS3 traces out the following error upon load complete of this page:

```
TypeError: Result of expression 'window.sessionStorage' [undefined] is not an object.
 at https://apis.google.com/_/scs/abc-static/_/js/k=gapi.gapi.en.bI438WBuHt0.O/m=googleapis_client,plusone/exm=appcirclepicker/rt=j/sv=1/d=1/ed=1/am=IA/rs=AItRSTNuPHIoFBjGmVBeSqIsgUIKEsrbzA/cb=gapi.loaded_1 : 13
 at https://apis.google.com/_/scs/abc-static/_/js/k=gapi.gapi.en.bI438WBuHt0.O/m=googleapis_client,plusone/exm=appcirclepicker/rt=j/sv=1/d=1/ed=1/am=IA/rs=AItRSTNuPHIoFBjGmVBeSqIsgUIKEsrbzA/cb=gapi.loaded_1 : 23
 at https://ssl.gstatic.com/gb/js/smm_5a5968e7804546d31a076ff436e35b36.js : 149
 at https://ssl.gstatic.com/gb/js/smm_5a5968e7804546d31a076ff436e35b36.js : 152
 at https://ssl.gstatic.com/gb/js/smm_5a5968e7804546d31a076ff436e35b36.js : 149
 at https://ssl.gstatic.com/gb/js/smm_5a5968e7804546d31a076ff436e35b36.js : 151
 at https://ssl.gstatic.com/gb/js/smm_5a5968e7804546d31a076ff436e35b36.js : 151
 at https://ssl.gstatic.com/gb/js/smm_5a5968e7804546d31a076ff436e35b36.js : 151
 at https://ssl.gstatic.com/gb/js/smm_5a5968e7804546d31a076ff436e35b36.js : 151
```

This problem is similar to this problem which I assume has been resolved, since this original problem had the accept button disabled: [TypeError upon authenticating user using Google OAuth 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18084954/typeerror-upon-authenticating-user-using-google-oauth-2#comment28096138_18084954)

My issue has the start button enabled, but when you click on it, it just grays out and the HTMLLoader (internal AIR browser) goes nowhere. I notice that the option to select which of the user's circles are allowed to see the app activity doesn't render correctly as well. Here is a screenshot of what I see:

[image]

Authenticating via a normal browser using the generated OAuth URL works fine.

Also would like to note that the cancel button works just fine in AIR. When the hit cancel, the HTMLLoader redirects to the redirect url with "?error=access_denied" like it should.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the G+ Sign-In javascript library?

Comment: No, I am following the instructions here: https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer to do oAuth in AS3 using HTMLLoader (Adobe AIR's internal browser). I am manually generating all oAuth URLs and submitting HTTP GET and POST requests to the server as outlined in that link.

Comment: Is this problem still present?